# Words that are both anagrams and synonyms of each other

Tags: wordplay, language, anagram

The puzzle is to find pairs of English words (A,B) such that A and B are both synonyms and anagrams of each other.

For example, *theater* and *theatre* (which are the British and American spelling of the same word), and *note* and *tone* which mean both the same in music and are also anagrams of each other

To avoid making this too broad and to avoid trivial examples like (theater, theatre), let's define the score of the pair to be the number of places where  the letters of the words differ. For example, for (theater, theatre) the score is 2, since the last letter differs (r versus e) and the next to last letter also differs (e versus r). For (note, tone), the score is also 2, since the first letter differs (n versus t) and the third also (t versus n). You're looking with the pair of words with the highest possible score.

**Note:** This question is inspired by  [Words that are anagrams of themselves](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/44773/words-that-are-anagrams-of-themselves) by user stib.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**8**

> alchemic chemical

Both mean something pertaining to the science, broadly defined.

> anaesthesis anesthesias

Both mean absence of feeling, but are different transliterations off Latin.

> depilate epilated

Both mean "having no hair".

**10**

> headspring springhead

Both mean "source".

#### Allowing for pluralization changes

**8**

> accoustrement accoutrements
>  synaesthesis synesthesias

**13**

> imperceptions misperception

#### Swapping parts of words

**8**

> outbreak breakout
>  hairbreadths hairsbreadth
>  handbreadths handsbreadth
>  macrophotograph photomacrograph
>  microphotograph photomicrograph

**9**

> phototelegraph telephotograph

**11**

> electrothermic thermoelectric

**12**

> electromagnetic magnetoelectric

If we indulge ourselves in medical terminology, the scores can get *very* high:

**14**

> encephalomeningitis meningoencephalitis

**15**

> duodenopancreatectomy pancreatoduodenectomy

**17**

> anatomicophysiologic physiologicoanatomic

Comment: 'imperceptions' = 'misperception'?

Answer (score 9):

**Score of 3**

- > **it's** vs **'tis** (actually a score of 4 if you count punctuation)

**Score of 4**

- > **evil** vs **vile**
- > **angered** vs **enraged**
- > **detail** vs **dilate** (both can mean to talk at length and in detail)

Hat tip to [Benjamin Kuykendall](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/338922/87724) for a list of anagram-synonyms (he also includes several more which I felt were not close enough synonyms to include, such as **name** vs **mean** or **punks** vs **spunk**).

If you want to 'cheat' a little more by including words which are anagrams merely by having parts of them swapped around, we can get larger scores ...

**Score of 5**

- > **sergeants-major** vs **sergeant-majors** (both seem to be acceptable plurals)

**Score of 6**

- > **lookout** vs **outlook**

Comment: How many milli seconds was the difference?

Comment: @Sid I was 3 seconds faster :-)

Comment: Why not just live = evil ;)

Answer (score 4):

I (thought that I had) found a 10:

> - identifiably, definability = $10$

Both mean that something can be identified or defined (Unfortunately I read identifiably as identifiability, so this doesn't count)

I have some smaller ones too:

> - cleaners, cleanser = $3$
> - detail, dilate = $4$
> - parental, paternal = $3$
> - recourse, resource = $2$
> - vileness, evilness = $4$

Comment: The highest-scoring among these are detail/dilate and vileness/evilness, both of which are already in my answer :-) Are you using the same (ELU) source as I found?

Comment: @randal'thor probably :P

Comment: @randal'thor think I found a 10 though

Comment: Those aren't synonyms: one of them is an adverb and the other is a noun.

Comment: @randal'thor aaaah I read identifiably as identifiability. Oops

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I found

> Vile and Evil (The Score is 4, if I got the rules correctly)
>  Team and Mate (Not exactly synonyms, but close) -Score of 4

And further answers as found

> Dilate and detail (Score is 4 for this as well)